# Unsupervised event prediction with time series data

Tags: machine-learning

I have to solve a problem using unsupervised time series forecast. I have a dataset where three columns are given, 
1. Endtime: when the row was generated ( it generates a row after each 54-55 seconds)
2. Min: min value of a wave
3. Max: max value of a wave.

Here I need to predict when we would observe an abrupt change (increase) in amplitude of the wave using unsupervised method. The increase may occur at the start or end or in middle. It's not fixed. ( Below is an example snippet of data and plot for your reference).

Please let me know if anyone has done similar projects. It would be a great help if you could give me some hints.[image: Example of data][image: Plot Example]

Comment: Is it supposed to be the same frequency of the wave, just the amplitude changes, i.e., $f(t)= A(t) sin(\omega t + \delta)$? Is the data in the first column the range of time over which the maximum and minimum values are observed?

Comment: Nope even the frequency might vary. The example data for the first column is 4, 59, 114, etc.

Comment: So in what sense is it a sinusoidal wave, if the frequency is not constant? It would probably help people understand your problem if you add a sketch showing what the signal looks like, and what data we are given.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I have edited my question. I discussed it with the data providers and they told me that they are not sure if it is a sine wave.

Comment: It is great there is a sketch now; but could you show on the sketch what you would call there "an abrupt change (increase) in amplitude of the wave"? Just trying to understand what kind of pattern we are supposed to find here. Also, are the sample values that you provided related to the data shown in the plot?

Comment: No the sample values are from a different file. I have multiple files with similar kind of data and I need to predict the time when we would observe an abrupt increase in the amplitude. Here they have not made any definition for abrupt but for simplicity we may define it as 50% change/increase in the amplitude.